# CSS3 without webkit and moz prefix

Tags: css, webkit, prefix

Is there a plugin or something of this nature that will allow me to write CSS like this:

```
transition:all 300ms; 
box-shadow:0 3px 2px #222; 
backface-visibility:hidden;
```

etc..

and for browser versions that require `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-o-` etc.. are added where required automatically as the stylesheet is loaded.

Comment: well, IDK about plugin but your hands cannot type few more characters?

Comment: @AspiringAqib this is about keeping css DRY. Vendor prefixes are bad for this because you have to repeat yourself 5 times for each statement that requires one. And it's worse when you're using keyframes as you'll have to repeat the entire block. With the prefixes, stylesheets end up being up to 5 times larger than necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, **-prefix-free** lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any CSS code, only when it’s needed. [Project's website](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/)

**Features**

- Processes every stylesheet in  or  elements and adds a vendor prefix where needed
- Processes elements with a style attribute and adds a vendor prefix where needed
- Takes care of new  or  elements, style attribute changes and CSSOM changes (requires plugin)
- Lets jQuery’s .css() method get and set unprefixed properties (requires plugin)

**Limitations**

- Prefixing code in @import-ed files is not supported
- Prefixing cross-origin linked stylesheets is not supported, unless they are CORS-enabled
- Unprefixed linked stylesheets won’t work locally in Chrome and Opera. You can change that for yourself though.
- Unprefixed values in inline styles (in the style attribute) won’t work in IE and Firefox < 3.6. Properties as well in Firefox < 3.6.

**How to use**

Just include prefixfree.js anywhere in your page. It is recommended to put it right after the stylesheets, to minimize FOUC

That’s it, you’re done!

**Browser Support**

The target browser support is **IE9+**, **Opera 10+**, **Firefox 3.5+**, **Safari 4+** and **Chrome on desktop** and **Mobile Safari**, **Android browser**, **Chrome and Opera Mobile on mobile**.

---

**Prefixmycss**

In addition, there is also an online service that lets you paste your unprefixed css code and returns the css with all the vendor prefixes. http://prefixmycss.com/

---

**CSS3Please**

[css3please.com](http://css3please.com/): a cross-browser css3 rule generator, produced by Jonathan Neal and Paul Irish. In addition to syncing and normalizing changes across the necessary properties, it also sneaks in IE support for a few features via IE filters.

---

**SASS and COMPASS**

Another way is that one of using the CSS preprocessor [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) with [COMPASS](http://compass-style.org/) mixins.

**Sass** is an extension of CSS3 which adds nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. Sass generates well formatted CSS and makes your stylesheets easier to organize and maintain.

**Compass** allows to extend Sass, it is full of reusable patterns, it allows to use sprites, CSS3 and typhography in an easy and standard way based on best practise.

---

Finally i suggest you to read an article from Paul Irish, one of the best frontend developers woking at Google: http://paulirish.com/2012/vendor-prefixes-are-not-developer-friendly/

Comment: I gradually added more content to my answer, so be sure to read it all.